# ANGULAR Error : core_1.InjectionToken is not a constructor

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular, npm, angular2-template

When i start my Angular 2 App the App is always in loading stage.

In the chrome dev console i can see the following:

```
 Error: (SystemJS) core_1.InjectionToken is not a constructor
    TypeError: core_1.InjectionToken is not a constructor
        at Object.eval (http://localhost:3000/node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/lib/translations.js:9:24)
```

My Setup is :

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 7.8.0
os: linux x64
@angular/common: 2.4.10
@angular/compiler: 2.4.10
@angular/core: 2.4.10
@angular/forms: 2.4.10
@angular/http: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser: 2.4.10
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 2.4.10
@angular/router: 3.0.2
@angular/upgrade: 2.4.10
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular 4 introduce `InjectionToken` to replace `OpaqueToken`, if you using Angular 2, please using `OpaqueToken` instead. But, I'd recommend update your app to Angular 4.

you can update your project by following this tutorial:
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-1.0-update